# Excel VBA: Adding/deleting rows based on cell values; issues with Offset()

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to automate the transcript evaluation process at my work. I have built a pretty hefty macro that I've been revisiting over the course of 6 months and I just can't seem to fully debug. See below:

```
Sub AddSchools()

Dim i As Long 'Add Rows Variable

Dim j As Integer
    j = Range("Courses1") 'Courses of School 1
Dim k As Integer
    k = Range("Courses2") 'Courses of School 2
Dim m As Integer
    m = Range("Courses3") 'Courses of School 3
Dim n As Integer
    n = Range("Courses4") 'Courses of School 4
Dim x As Integer
    x = Range("Courses5") 'Courses of School 5
Dim y As Integer
    y = Range("Courses6") 'Courses of School 6

Dim InsertHere As Range
Set InsertHere = Worksheets("Eval Sheet").Range("A15:L15")

If k <> 0 Then '1.0) Add Rows for School 1 and then School 2
   For i = 1 To (j - 1)
        Worksheets("Eval Sheet").Activate
        With ActiveSheet
            InsertHere.Select 'Selects School 1 + Inserts (j-1) Rows here
            Selection.EntireRow.Insert Shift = xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=0
        End With
    Next i
    If m <> 0 Then '2.0) Add Rows for School 2 and then School 3
        For i = 1 To (k - 1)
            Worksheets("Eval Sheet").Activate
            With ActiveSheet
                InsertHere.Offset(5 + (j - 1), 0).Select 'Moves Selection to School 2 + Inserts (k-1) Rows here
                Selection.EntireRow.Insert Shift = xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=0
            End With
        Next i
        If n <> 0 Then '3.0) Add Rows for School 3 and then School 4
            For i = 1 To (m - 1)
                Worksheets("Eval Sheet").Activate
                With ActiveSheet
                    InsertHere.Offset(9 + j + k, 0).Select 'Moves Selection to School 3 + Inserts (m-1) Rows here
                    Selection.EntireRow.Insert Shift = xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=0
                End With
            Next i
            If x <> 0 Then '4.0) Add Rows for School 4 and then School 5
                For i = 1 To (n - 1)
                    Worksheets("Eval Sheet").Activate
                    With ActiveSheet
                        InsertHere.Offset(14 + j + k + m, 0).Select 'Moves Selection to School 4 + Inserts (n-1) Rows here
                        Selection.EntireRow.Insert Shift = xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=0
                    End With
                Next i
                If y <> 0 Then '5.0) Add Rows for School 5 and then School 6
                    For i = 1 To (x - 1)
                        Worksheets("Eval Sheet").Activate
                        With ActiveSheet
                            InsertHere.Offset(19 + j + k + m + n, 0).Select 'Moves Selection to School 5 + Inserts (x-1) Rows here
                            Selection.EntireRow.Insert Shift = xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=0
                        End With
                    Next i
                    For i = 1 To (y - 1) '6.0) Add Rows for School 6
                        Worksheets("Eval Sheet").Activate
                        With ActiveSheet
                            InsertHere.Offset(24 + j + k + m + n + x, 0).Select 'Moves Selection to School 6 + Inserts (y-1) Rows here
                            Selection.EntireRow.Insert Shift = xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=0
                        End With
                    Next i
                Else '5.1) Add Rows for ONLY School 5
                    For i = 1 To (x - 1)
                        Worksheets("Eval Sheet").Activate
                        With ActiveSheet
                            InsertHere.Offset(20 + j + k + m, 0).Select 'Moves Selection to School 5 + Inserts x Rows here
                            Selection.EntireRow.Insert Shift = xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=0
                        End With
                    Next i
                Dim Delete5 As Long '5.2) Delete School 6
                    For Delete5 = 1 To 5 Step 1
                    Rows(31 + j + k + m + n + x).EntireRow.Delete
                    Next
                End If 'End of Process 5
            Else '4.1) Add Rows for ONLY School 4
                For i = 1 To (n - 1)
                    Worksheets("Eval Sheet").Activate
                    With ActiveSheet
                        InsertHere.Offset(15 + j + k, 0).Select 'Moves Selection to School 4 + Inserts n Rows here
                        Selection.EntireRow.Insert Shift = xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=0
                    End With
                Next i
            Dim Delete4 As Long '4.2) Delete Schools 5-6
                For Delete4 = 1 To 10 Step 1
                Rows(27 + j + k + m + n).EntireRow.Delete
                Next
            End If 'End of Process 4
        Else '3.1) Add Rows for ONLY School 3
            For i = 1 To (m - 1)
                    Worksheets("Eval Sheet").Activate
                    With ActiveSheet
                        InsertHere.Offset(7 + j + k, 0).Select 'Moves Selection to School 3 + Inserts m Rows here
                        Selection.EntireRow.Insert Shift = xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=0
                    End With
            Next i
        Dim Delete3 As Long '3.2) Delete Schools 4-6
            For Delete3 = 1 To 14 Step 1
            Rows(22 + j + k + m).EntireRow.Delete
            Next
        End If 'End of Process 3
    Else '2.1) Add Rows for ONLY School 2
        For i = 1 To (k - 1)
            Worksheets("Eval Sheet").Activate
            With ActiveSheet
                InsertHere.Offset(5, 0).Select 'Moves Selection to School 2 + Inserts k Rows here
                Selection.EntireRow.Insert Shift = xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=0
            End With
        Next i
    Dim Delete2 As Long '2.2) Delete Schools 3-6
        For Delete2 = 1 To 19 Step 1
        Rows(17 + j + k).EntireRow.Delete
        Next
    End If 'End of Process 2
Else '1.1) Add Rows for ONLY School 1
    For i = 1 To (j - 1)
        Worksheets("Eval Sheet").Activate
        With ActiveSheet
            InsertHere.Select 'Selects School 1 + Inserts j Rows here
            Selection.EntireRow.Insert Shift = xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=0
        End With
    Next i
Dim Delete1 As Long '1.2) Delete Schools 2-6
    For Delete1 = 1 To 24 Step 1
    Rows(12 + j).EntireRow.Delete
    Next
End If 'End of Process 1
Worksheets("Eval Sheet").Range("A10").Select
End Sub
```

I have found that when a cell value is 1, it throws off all the Offsets, so I 
was tried the following, but I got "Compile error: Else without If."

```
 If j > 1 Then
            For i = 1 To (j - 1)
        Else
            For i = 1 To 1
        End If
```

Any help would be appreciated. Also, feel free to let me know if anything is redundant -- I'm somewhat of an amateur at VBA. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot interleave structures.

Comment: `For i = 1 To IIf(j > 1, j - 1, 1)` should work.

Comment: right above `If m <> 0 Then` you have a `Next i` without a for loop before it. Is this an oversight or is that line gone because it is the one you are writing your question about?

Comment: @VincentG Thanks! This helps a lot but the add rows function is still thrown off when the first value (j) is 1.

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 I accidentally took it out when posting here but it's still in my code; it should say `For i to (j-1).` I'll edit that now.